# Upgrade to Google Analytics API v4 instead of waiting for new alpha API to become available?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am currently on Google Analytics API v3. Since Google Analytics 4 (GA4) just came out, I am looking into upgrading to API v4, however, I have noticed that the API v4 does not include GA4 properties and the API that handles GA4 properties is currently in alpha (I believe it's Data Reporting v1).

Will it be more work for me to update my existing application to API v4 from v3, and then when the beta or general release for the Data Reporting v1 arrives, upgrade then, or should I wait to upgrade from API v3 to

I am under the impression that v4 doesn't have the ability to pull GA4 properties, however, since it runs on completely new endpoints and Google has mentioned all future development will be on v4 then I should just move to it so its less work when the newest API comes out with those features. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marshall,

You are correct, the Google Analytics Reporting API V4 cannot access GA4 properties, you need to use the Google Analytics Data API V1 in order to do this. New features development will only be done in the Data API. Both APIs are conceptually similar, but the decision mostly depends on which type of properties you need to access.

As a side note, I believe the Data API is slated to graduate to Beta in a matter of weeks.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics Team